# Animation on hover a shapeless zone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create specific hover zones on a web page, not a "squared zone".
I've got here a nice watercolour background image and I want users be able to click on these zones.

A picture tells more than a thousand words so here is the original background image :

https://i.ibb.co/bQK1MZB/background-home-1080p.png

And here is a zone I would like to be hovered (in red) :

https://i.ibb.co/ng9dFRc/Sans-titre-2.png

So how can I define strictly this zone, so if the user hover like 5px outside it, it doesn't hover. Is it only CSS ?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) should work great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it can be achieved by using `clip-path` for a transparent image. As a clip path you will need to draw a custom SVG graphics (in Adobe Illustrator, I guess).
Look at this example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af3924ys/1/).
Here in example I used red image to make the result visible